# Flash button/symbol

Tags: flash, actionscript, flashdevelop

I've created a button (symbol), and added a OVER state, which covers a bigger boundary than the UP state.

However when I add the symbol/button to my stage, the roll over activates on any area covered by the over state, where I only really need it covering the UP state boundary.

Does anyone know of clipping the region covered, so mouse over is only trigged by the boundaries of the UP state.

Is there a way or work around to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make button in stage ("convert to button" option) inside it you got 4 frames for it states. One of them is HIT - there draw your over-hit shape.

If you use AS create a new Sprite with shape taht will be your hit region. This shape sholud have alpha=0. Then add events listeners to it or other code you use for button actions.

If you have problems, just read the documentation on flash. Everything is there.

Online docs:
 [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/UsingFlash/WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7dbf.html)

Comment: Thanks Konrad, I'll give it a go, I was getting a little overwhelmed by flash, not being used to it or it's terminology (1 week in and beginning to see how much potential it has)